# How to actually use Python in Android Studio with Chaquopy?

Tags: android, python, chaquopy

I want to write Android apps using Chaquopy. I followed the first few steps from https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html to integrate python into studio. My question is where do I actually write the python code in android studio (should i write it in jupyter notebook and upload it somehow or can I create a py file in the studio environment?) and is their anything I should add in addition to the steps mentioned on the website above?

Comment: You can write the Python code in Android Studio or any other editor. [The documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#source-code) explains where the code should go, and the [example apps](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/index.html#introduction) provide a simple starting point.

Comment: If you ask any more questions about Chaquopy, make sure to use the word Chaquopy in the title, and ideally add the tag as well. (The original version of this question didn't mention Chaquopy at all other than in the link to the documentation, so it was incorrectly closed for being a vague duplicate.)